# Sort by category id rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, categories

I have created a application where you can sort subjects and download academic files accordingly.
I first created the app where the user can view all categories and there is a dropdown box to sort all the categories and display it accordingly.

Now, my client wants only the subject related user to view only their respective materials. Other categories must not be viewable to them.

For Example if i have faculty="Ruby" on my users table. I must only be able to view all the Ruby files other files must not be displayed. Please Help me integrate this function to my app.

This is my current working index.html.erb and assignment_controller (here we can sort according to category but it displays all files)

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_assignment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    if params[:category].blank?
      @assignments = Assignment.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
      @assignments = Assignment.where(:category_id => @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end


  def show
  end

  def new
    @assignment = current_user.assignments.build
    @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}
  end


  def edit
    @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}
  end


  def create

    @assignment = current_user.assignments.build(assignment_params)
    @assignment.category_id = params[:category_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: 'Assignment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assignment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    authorize @assignment
    @assignment.category_id = params[:category_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignment.update(assignment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: 'Assignment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @assignment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    authorize @assignment
    @assignment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to assignments_url, notice: 'Assignment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
  private

    def user_not_authorized
      flash[:warning] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
      redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
    end
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_assignment
      @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def assignment_params
      params.require(:assignment).permit(:title, :detail, :due_date, :category_id, :attachment)
    end
end
```

ERB file:

```
<% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<br />
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Sort By Model Name
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
          <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:category] == category.name %>">
            <%= link_to category.name, assignments_path(category: category.name), class: "link" %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>

<h1 class="current-category"><%= params[:category] %></h1>
<% if @assignments.count == 0 %>

  <h1>There are no file uploaded for this Model</h1>
  <% else %>  
<br />
<h1>Listing Assignments</h1>

<%= current_user.faculty %>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Detail</th>
      <th>Due date</th>
      <th>Days Remaining</th>
      <th>Latest Updated</th>
      <th>Download Link</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @assignments.each do |assignment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= assignment.title %></td>
        <td><%= assignment.detail %></td>
        <td><%= assignment.due_date %></td>
        <td> <%= (assignment.due_date.to_i - Time.now.to_i)/86400%></td>
        <td><%= distance_of_time_in_words(assignment.updated_at, Time.now)  %> ago</td>
        <td><%= link_to "Download File", assignment.attachment_url %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', assignment %></td>
        <% if policy(assignment).destroy? %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_assignment_path(assignment) %></td>

        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', assignment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td><% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<% end %> 

<%= link_to 'New Assignment', new_assignment_path %>
```

Comment: i did 
<% if (assignment.category_id == current_user.faculty) %>
in the index.html.erb page to only display if category id in assignment is equals to faculty id in users. but it lists all blank. nothing is shown.

Comment: is there a difference between "category" and "faculty" in your app ?

Comment: @niceman NO.  i made faculty as integer to compare with Category ID.  Both are same. just in different tables

Comment: different tables , hmmm do you mean a foreign key ?

Comment: Ok i will explain my problem properly.
Users table has - email,password,admin,faculty(which is same as category_id)
Assignments table has- tile,detail,date,category_id
Assignments table and user table have relationship.
now i want to compare assignments category id and current users category id. and only display the contents related to that category_id in index page.

Comment: I suggest you have a category table with relationship to Users and to Assignments, you can then join the three tables and give that(with projection ofcourse) as the result.